# How can I show the flag's text as tooltip in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Earlier I found that flag's text can be shown as a tooltip in the highstock chart. But now that's cannot be found. Is that remove from the highchart library or is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think that your issue may be related to this GitHub topic: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6820

Comment: Thank You, That solve my problem.  Is there any method to only enable flag tooltip @GrzegorzBlachliński

Comment: You should be able to use tooltip.formatter in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/3cgsu8gL/ If my example will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer